# do 3D perpendicular lines have negative reciprocal slopes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

it's stated in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/799859/386009) that the directional vector is a nice analog for the slope in $3D$ space

$⟨x,y,z⟩=⟨x_0,y_0,z_0⟩+t⟨m_x,m_y,m_z⟩$

now suppose I have two perpidicular lines $L1$ and $L2$ where $L_1$ is

$(a,b,c) + t (m_x,m_y,m_z)$.

The slopes of the perpendicular lines should be the negative reciprocals of each other thus I tried to define $L2$ as

$⟨x_2,y_2,z_2⟩ = (a,b,c) + t (-1/m_x,-1/m_y,-1/m_z)$

for many reasons, clearly that is not true, e.g. the dot product between the two directional vectors would equal $-3$  not $zero$,  is the directional vector the same thing as the slope? do the perpendicular lines only have negative reciprocal slopes in $2D$ space? if not, what would be a nice analog to explain that fact in $3D$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that in two dimensions, the slope (when defined) is the ratio of the components of the directional vector:
$$ \langle x,y\rangle = \langle x_0, y_0\rangle + t\langle m_x, m_y\rangle \land m_x \neq 0
\implies y = \frac{m_y}{m_x} x + \left(y_0 - \frac{m_y}{m_x}x_0 \right). $$

Note that flipping the signs of $m_x$ and $m_y$ simultaneously does nothing to the line at all.
The line given by 
$\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x_0, y_0\rangle + t\langle -m_x, -m_y\rangle$
is exactly the same as the line given by
$\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x_0, y_0\rangle + t\langle m_x, m_y\rangle.$

The "negative reciprocal" rule is actually telling you to change
$\frac{m_y}{m_x}$ to $-\frac{m_x}{m_y}.$ A simple way to do this is to swap the two components and negate *just one* of them:
$\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x_0, y_0\rangle + t\langle m_y, -m_x\rangle.$
Notice how the dot product shows that the new vector $\langle m_y, -m_x\rangle$
is perpendicular to the old vector $\langle m_x, m_y\rangle$:
$$ 
\langle m_x, m_y\rangle \cdot \langle m_y, -m_x\rangle = m_x m_y + m_y(-m_x) = 0.
$$

In short, even in two dimensions, the rule is *not* to take the negative reciprocal of each component of the direction vector simultaneously.

In two dimensions there is only one line perpendicular to a given line,
but in three dimensions, there are many lines perpendicular to a given line.
We therefore have more choices for the direction vector for the perpendicular line.
Given a direction vector $\langle m_x, m_y, m_z\rangle,$
where $m_x$ and $m_y$ are not both zero,
one possible choice of a perpendicular vector is 
$\langle m_y, -m_x, 0\rangle,$
which is an application of the negative reciprocal rule to the first two dimensions;
this still works, even in three dimensions, as long as we make sure not to allow the third dimension to make the dot product non-zero.
(That is why the third component of the perpendicular vector is zero.)

Another vector perpendicular to both of these is
$\langle m_x m_z, m_y m_z, -(m_x^2 + m_y^2)\rangle.$

Answer (score 4):

The "negative reciprocal" argument in the plane is just a restatement of the more natural dot product condition. In the plane a line has a direction vector too: it can be written as
$$
(x,y) = (a,b) + t(m_x, m_y) .
$$
The slope when the line is not parallel to the $y$=axis is then $m_y/m_x$.

Now the assertion that the product of two slopes is $-1$ is equivalent to the assertion that the dot product of the two direction vectors is $0$.